# How to group by columns with commas in their names in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to group by some columns that contain commas using data.table. Is there an elegant way of doing it? The following does not work:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=rnorm(10), y=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1), z=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))
names(dt) <- c("x", "a,b", "c,d")
dt
groupByColumns <- c("a,b", "c,d")
dt[,mean(x), by=groupByColumns]
dt[,mean(x), by=c("a,b", "c,d")]
```

Both variants give you

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , mean(x), by = c("a,b", "c,d")) : 
  'by' is a character vector length 2 but one or more items include a comma. Either pass a vector of column names (which can contain spaces, but no commas), or pass a vector length 1 containing comma separated column names. See ?data.table for other possibilities.
```

Comment: `dt[,mean(x), by=.(\`a,b\`, \`c,d\`)]`

Comment: `dt[,mean(x), by=mget(groupByColumns)]`.